# Azure Web Apps directly from Repo and not requiring to setting up the server?

Tags: django, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service

So we can deploy Java apps directly from your GitHub account ? - no need to setup server with Java setup etc - the azure web app will recognize the GitHub repo as a Java app (like springboot) and deploy the code and setup Java + SpringBoot automatically.

Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect. I am only interested in deploying a springboot / django app if I don't need to take care of the actual intricacies of setting up a server.

Comment: Use _Azure Pipelines_ to set-up a CD (Continuous Deployment) process that binds a repo (with a build step) to an Azure App Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-azure-pipelines?tabs=yaml

Comment: Is there no option to set Django or SpringBoot as a web app and get the azure-web-app-service to automatically set this up for me ?

Comment: I'm referring to this tutorial - https://stories.mlh.io/deploying-a-basic-django-app-using-azure-app-services-71ec3b21db08 - so pipeline is only meant for automatica deployment ? For now I'll use the dashboard to deploy manually - but I was wondering if I should be involved in setting up any parts of django from a server point of view.

Comment: ...but Springboot and Django are application frameworks - you can't just "deploy" an "empty" Spring/Django web-app - they're not like WordPress or phpBB or DotNetNuke. Are you wanting to get a _scaffolded_ web-application pre-deployed for you... I guess? If so, then no, Azure App Services are not intended as a scaffolding platform.

Comment: Odd - for the Django tutorial in the link above, if I give a requirements.txt file the deployment comnsole is able to detect and install the modules. https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:4800/0*wSCF8t3xxLluZCPG - all there's left to do is for me to push to GitHub or Azure Repos, right ?

Comment: My understanding was that Azure Web App Service is akin to DigitalOcean App Platform.

Comment: It will be a lot easier if you try to bake a container image for your Spring Boot/Django apps. Then deploying it to Azure App Service, or any other container environment is just easy like a breeze. Container CI/CD is also well covered by GitHub Actions or any other CI/CD platform.

Comment: @Lex Li - Ok, so I checked this tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?tabs=django%2Cwindows - is this what you're referring to ? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-django-postgresql-sample-app/blob/main/.github/workflows/azure-dev.yaml

Comment: `    
container:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-dev-cli-apps:latest
`

Comment: I echo with Lex Li. This is the best approach possible in view of its versatility.